# Akka Net Integration Test

Tags: c#, akka.net, testkit

I have a fairly simply scenario where I want to do a straight forward integration test. High level overview, is:

- I have an `actor` which responds to a message called `PlaceOrder`
- I want to verify this actor `publishes` another message upon receiving `PlaceOrder`, in this case `OrderPlaced`

The trouble is, for an integration test I can assert that the message has been published via `ExpectMsg<OrderPlaced>`. But, I was also expecting it to invoke any actors handling that message too?

Perhaps my understanding of the `TestKit` is incorrect here but when inheriting from it you get:

- `ActorOfAsTestActorRef<T>`
- `ActorOf<T>`
- `Sys.ActorOf(...)`

My impression was, `ActorOf<T>` and `Sys.ActorOf(...)` would behave like a real actor system whereas the `ActorOfAsTestActorRef<T>` would be ideal for strictly unit tests and swallow any messages an actor may in turn send.

For example, these are my 2 actors in question:

```
public class PlaceOrderActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public PlaceOrderActor()
    {
        this.Receive<PlaceOrderMessage>(
            message =>
            {
                this.Handle(message);
            });
    }

    private void Handle(PlaceOrderMessage message)
    {
        Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<Foo>()).Tell(new OrderPlaced(message.CustomerId, message.OrderItems));
    }
}

public class Foo : ReceiveActor
{
    public Foo()
    {
        this.Receive<OrderPlaced>(
            m =>
            {
            });
    }
}
```

My test looks like this. The odd thing I have to orchestrate this integration test myself, i.e. I check that the `OrderPlaced` has been published and then explicitly send a message to `Foo`:

```
[TestFixture]
public class IntegrationTest : TestKit
{
    [Test]
    public void When_Placing_An_Order()
    {
        var message = new PlaceOrderMessage(
            "123",
            new List<OrderItem>
            {
                new OrderItem("Product ABC", 2)
            });

        this.ActorOfAsTestActorRef<PlaceOrderActor>().Tell(message);

        var orderPlaced = this.ExpectMsg<OrderPlaced>();

        //if (orderPlaced != null)
        //{
            //this.ActorOfAsTestActorRef<Foo>().Tell(orderPlaced);
        //}
    }
}
```

What I am expecting is, by sending the message `PlaceOrder` this should invoke `Foo` as it handles `OrderPlaced`. I shouldn't need to have the bits commented out in the test?

Can this be done or am I going about this completely wrong?

Thanks in advance, DS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PlaceOrderActor` doesn't have a reference to the `FooActor`, it responds to the `Sender`, which is the Testkit actor.

If you want the `FooActor` to receive the `OrderPlaced` message, you're going to need to tell it the message in your `PlaceOrderActor.Handle()` method.  You'll likely need to create the `FooActor` as a child of the `PlaceOrderActor`, or otherwise resolve the reference to it if it's elsewhere in your system (in this case there is no `FooActor` running in the system at all).  How does this work in your actual (ie. non-test) system, or does this only exist as test code so far?

Be aware that if you send the `OrderPlaced` message to the `FooActor`, and don't tell any message back to the Sender of `PlaceOrderActor`, there will be no observable effect from within your test method, so your `FooActor` will need to respond either directly to the original sender, or back to the `PlaceOrderActor` which in turn can respond to the original sender.

Comment: I was on the akka net gitter room about this and it seems as though I don't have the foo actor running hence the message is being swallowed. I believe in my setup I simply need to add ActorOf Foo and it should work. You are right I have only tried this from a test perspective. I have something extremely similar to this running in a console app.

Comment: You're post got me thinking so I created a `Client` which simply serves as a sender of messages to the `Server`. This seems to work fine, i.e. I send `PlaceOrderMessage` which is handled by an `PlaceOrderActor`. I then use `Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<Foo>()).Tell(new OrderPlaced(message.CustomerId, message.OrderItems));`. However, when using TestKit this message is swallowed?

Comment: Apologies you are correct. Created a child actor worked a treat. The problem I was just experiencing happened to be I was using `ActorOfAsTestActorRef` which runs on a separate thread to `Sys.ActorOf()` (to my knowledge) and hence the assert of `ExpectMsg<>` was failing. Updating post to show the working solution.