# Writing Integration tests for AKKA HTTP end point

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest, akka-http, akka-testkit

I am quite confused on how to write a integration test for a Akka Http end point. In Java its as easy as use Dropwizard rule to launch the API locally and just carry out get or post for the local end point. The test has the env var needed. I am looking for the same in AKKA HTTP

I would like to bring up the application locally and follow the structure as mentioned in this post.
[Akka Net Integration Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314597/akka-net-integration-test)

Are there any good examples of this

This is what i have in the controller.

```scala
     @GET
      @Path("/jobs")
      @Consumes(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      @Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      @Operation(
        summary = "See Status of All Workflow Jobs",
        description = "See Status of All Workflow Jobs.",
        method = "GET",
        security = Array(new SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")))
      def getJobs: Route = jobs
```

I wrote the following test. Just like junit has before how do i launch application locally

```
    "The service" should {
    "return jobs response" in {
      val headers =
        RawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer token")
      val httpRequest =
        HttpRequest(
          HttpMethods.GET,
          "http://localhost:8080/jobs?ids=20388241",
          scala.collection.immutable.Seq(headers))

      def sendRequest(): Future[String] = {
        val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(httpRequest)
        Await.result(responseFuture, 5.seconds)
        val entityFuture: Future[HttpEntity.Strict] =
          responseFuture.flatMap(response => response.entity.toStrict(10.seconds))
        entityFuture.map(entity => entity.data.utf8String)
      }

      val mapper = new ObjectMapper
      mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

      sendRequest().map(response =>
        assert(
          mapper.readValue(response, classOf[WorkflowsResponse]).workflows.get(0).workflowId > 0))
    }
  }
```

Response String is a json String of type Workflow Response. How do i fix the above test to launch application and run the test

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Are you using the annotations just for generating swagger docs? what's the error you are getting when you run the test? Based on the exmaple I would guess you are using scalatest. Please add details about which libs and versions you are using, the command you executed and the error you got

Comment: I updated the code. I am looking at a drop wizard rule where i can bring up the application before running the tests.

Comment: The Akka documentation should contain all you need. See for instance https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html

Comment: I am looking for application rule just like in drop wizard to bring up the app and run test.. Above test works provided i run the application and then run this, I want all of it in the same test

Comment: It's not clear for me what exactly you are looking for. I don't know how drop wizard work. The routing testkit lets you send request to the endpoint and then validate the response you got. Could you detail what exactly you want to assert in your tests? what are the elements that should be part of the test? when you said integration test, I imagine that you want to add external things like a database, a message queue, a storage system or something like that.